# Can we skip a specfic command while tcl is running source.?

Tags: tcl

Eg.  `get_abc`, `get_xyz` command which generate collection, `set_pqr` receives collection are custom commands and following is tcl file

```
#Tcl file start
get_abc
get_xyz
set_pqr -object [get_abc]
#Tcl file end
```

Now the requirement is we need to skip the `set_pqr` command and this tcl file is big and read only, we can't change it.
Now we added this handling in `set_pqr` command callback to skip processing, but still `get_abc` command in same line get processed which is anyway to be discarded and not needed when the collection goes to `set_pqr`. Also we can't skip `get_abc` from software because its valid and can be used at other places.

Does tcl provides capability to skip the full line of `set_pqr`

Comment: Essentially you want `set_pqr` to act like a comment?

Comment: Yes, we want to comment out the set_pqr line

Answer (score 0):

The only ways to make Tcl do what you want are to not use standard `source` to load the command. Let's write our own version instead:

```
proc skippingSource {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set code [read $f]
    close $f
    # Comment out the offending lines; this is a cheap hack BTW
    set code [regsub -all -line {^set_pqr } $code "#set_pqr "]
    # Override [info script] until this procedure returns
    info script $filename
    uplevel 1 $code
}
```

Now we just need to use `skippingSource` instead of `source`. We can of course call it directly, the easiest method, or we can substitute in for `source`:

```
# Keep the original in case we want to put it back
rename source originalSource
rename skippingSource source
```

Comment: Only `#` works like a comment; comments are syntax, not commands.

Answer (score 0):

You redefine `set_pqr` to a proc that does nothing:

```
# Back up original set_pqr
rename set_pqr set_pqr_original

# Make new proc that does nothing
proc set_pqr {args} {}
```

Now you can `source` the file and each `seq_pqr` command will do nothing (and takes an arbitrary number of arguments).

When you need the original command back again:

```
rename set_pqr_original set_pqr
```

This whole thing could be wrapped up in one proc too:

```
proc source_with_skip {filename "skip_commands {}"} {
    foreach command $skip_commands {
        rename $command ${command}_original
    }

    source $filename

    foreach command $skip_commands {
        rename ${command}_original $command
    }
}

% source my_file.tcl set_pqr
```

Note that the above may not be sufficient if the procs are in different namespaces than the current namespace.